# Filter Dataframe by second dataframe

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have two dataframes.

`selectedcustomersa` is a dataframe with information about 50 customers. Fist column is the name (Group.1).

`selectedcustomersb` is another dataframe (same structure) with information about 2000 customers and customers from `selectedcustomersa` are included there.

I want `selctedcustomersb` without the customers from `selctedcustomersa`.

I tried:

```
newselectedcustomersb<-filter(selectedcustomersb,  Group.1!=selectedcustomersa$Group.1)
```

Comment: You could use `setdiff`. something like `newselectedcustomersb <- selectedcustomersb[selectedcustomersb$Group.1 %in% setdiff(selectedcustomersb$Group.1, selectedcustomersa$Group.1),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `anti_join` in dplyr as follows. It will work across multiple columns and such.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), y = 1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(x = c('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), z = 1:4)
df <- anti_join(df2, df1)
df
  x z
1 e 3
2 f 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
newselectedcustomersb <- filter(selectedcustomersb, !(Group.1 %in% selectedcustomersa$Group.1))
```